# Will the System Restore bring back Ransomware even after using an anti-virus?

Tags: windows-7, virus, anti-virus, system-restore, ransomware

I have been attacked by a Ransomware STOP djvu vs extension .npsk. I will be able to remove it soon, but after that, I want to use System Restore to recover my original file that not been encrypted yet. When I can’t boot, I used the only earlier point (4pm 3/22) so that I can install anti-virus. But when it displayed “successfully restart”, the point is “7am 3/23” when I’ve been attacked, and all the file is encrypted, the virus is acting. So, can you answer me whether if I remove the malware and use the point before attacked, it will bring back virus? Additionally, will my files be original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to restore from your backup. That is the only practical way.